# restore foreign key on magento database

Tags: database, magento, foreign-keys

i have a database which is used by a magento site. The problem is that the database does not have any foreign keys on tables. My question is if there's a way to restore this relations between tables. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Magento repair tools for recover table relations.

[click here](https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Magento+1.x+Database+Repair+Tool) for steps.

You just need to setup another fresh DB of same magento version.